# Templated class specialization where template argument is a template

Tags: c++, templates

I wondering if something similar to this is possible.  Basically, I have a templated class that occasionally takes objects of templated classes.  I would like to specialize it (or just a member function)for a specific templated class, but the 'generic' form of that class.

```
template<typename T, typename S>
class SomeRandomClass
{
    //put something here
};

template<typename T>
class MyTemplateClass
{
    void DoSomething(T & t) {
       //...something
    }
};

template<>
void MyTemplateClass< SomeRandomClass<???> >::DoSomething(SomeRandomClass<???> & t)
{
    //something specialized happens here
}
```

Replacing the question marks with appropriate types (double, etc) works, but I would like it to remain generic.  I don't know what to put there, as any types wouldn't have been defined. I've looked around, and learned about template template parameters, and tried various combinations to no avail. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's possible to specialize the class like this

```
template <>
template <typename T,typename S>
class MyTemplateClass <SomeRandomClass<T,S> >
{
    void DoSomething(SomeRandomClass<T,S>& t) { /* something */ }
};
```

It's not possible to specialize just the member method, because the specialization is on the class as a whole, and you have to define a new class. You can, however, do

```
template <>
template <typename T,typename S>
class MyTemplateClass <SomeRandomClass<T,S> >
{
    void DoSomething(SomeRandomClass<T,S>& t);
};

template <>
template <typename T,typename S>
void MyTemplateClass<SomeRandomClass<T,S> >::DoSomething(SomeRandomClass<T,S>& t)
{
    // something
}
```

to split up the declaration and definition.

Comment: Can you specialize a templated function the same way?

Comment: @Mirco just a bare function, not a part of a class? You don't actually need the initial empty template<> for that case, since you don't have a containing template class to specialize.

Comment: Let say that I have a prototype `template <typename T> T fun(void);` and I want to specialize it for all, say, std::list types. Can I obtain something like `template<> template<typename S> std::list<S> fun<std::list<S>>(void) { /*return sth*/ };`?

Comment: Specializing only on the return type? I don't know for sure if a partial specialization like that is even allowed. But that would make a good question to post and get an answer.

Answer (score 28):

I'm not completely sure why @Ryan Calhoun [specialized the way he did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4200397/27678) but here's a more terse example:

```
// class we want to specialize with later on
template<typename T, typename S>
struct SomeRandomClass
{
    int myInt = 0;
};

// non-specialized class
template<typename T>
struct MyTemplateClass
{
    void DoSomething(T & t) 
    {
       std::cout << "Not specialized" << std::endl;
    }
};

// specialized class
template<typename T, typename S>
struct MyTemplateClass< SomeRandomClass<T, S> >
{
    void DoSomething(SomeRandomClass<T,S> & t) 
    {
       std::cout << "Specialized" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

You can see that you don't need the redundant syntax used in the accepted answer:

```
template<>
template<typename T, typename S>
```

[Working Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fee30115e6d058be)

---

#### Alternative

You can use type_traits and tag-dispatch within your non-specialized class to specialize just the function.

Let's first make a concept for `is_random_class`:

```
// concept to test for whether some type is SomeRandomClass<T,S>
template<typename T>
struct is_random_class : std::false_type{};

template<typename T, typename S>
struct is_random_class<SomeRandomClass<T,S>> : std::true_type{};
```

And then let's declare our `MyTemplateClass` again, but this time **not** templated (because we're not specializing) so we'll call it `MyNonTemplatedClass`:

```
class MyNonTemplatedClass
{
    
    public:
    template<typename T>
    void DoSomething(T & t) 
    {
       DoSomethingHelper(t, typename is_random_class<T>::type());
    }
    // ...
```

Notice how `DoSomething` is now templated, and it's actually calling a helper instead of implementing the logic itself?

Let's break down the line:

```
DoSomethingHelper(t, typename is_random_class<T>::type());
```

- `t` is as-before; we're passing along the argument of type `T&`
- `typename is_random_class<T>::type()`

  - `is_random_class<T>` is our concept, and since it derives from `std::true_type` or `std::false_type` it will have a `::type` defined within the class (Google for "type traits")
  - `::type()` 'instantiates' the type specified by `is_random_class<T>::type`. I say it in quotation marks because we're really going to throw that away as we see later
  - `typename` is required because the compiler doesn't know that `is_random_clas<T>::type` actually names a type.

Now we're ready to look at the rest of `MyNonTemplatedClass`:

```
    private:
    //use tag dispatch. If the compiler is smart it won't actually try to instantiate the second param
    template<typename T>
    void DoSomethingHelper(T&t, std::true_type)
    {
        std::cout << "Called DoSomething with SomeRandomClass whose myInt member has value " << t.myInt << std::endl;
    }
    
    template<typename T>
    void DoSomethingHelper(T&t, std::false_type)
    {
        std::cout << "Called DoSomething with a type that is not SomeRandomClass\n";
    }
};
```

[Full Working Demo v2 Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6def5b162f0d93e)

Notice that our helper functions are named the same, but overloaded on the second parameter's type. We don't give a name to the parameter because we don't need it, and hopefully the compiler will optimize it away while still calling the proper function.

Our concept forces `DoSomethingHelper(T&t, std::true_type)` only if `T` is of type `SomeRandomClass`, and calls the other for any other type.

#### The benefit of tag dispatch

The main benefit of tag dispatch here is that you don't need to specialize your entire class if you only mean to specialize a single function within that class.

The tag dispatching will happen at compile time, which you wouldn't get if you tried to perform branching on the concept solely within the `DoSomething` function.

---

### C++17

In **C++17**, this problem becomes embarrassingly easy using variable templates (C++14) and `if constexpr` (C++17).

We use our type_trait to create a variable template that will give us a `bool` value of `true` if the provided type `T` is of type `SomeRandomClass`, and false otherwise:

```
template<class T>
constexpr bool is_random_class_v = is_random_class<T>::value;
```

Then, we use it in a `if constexpr` expression that only compiles the appropriate branch (and discards the other at compile-time, so the check is at *compile-time*, not run-time):

```
struct MyNonTemplatedClass
{
    template<class T>
    void DoSomething(T& t) 
    {
        if constexpr(is_random_class_v<T>)
            std::cout << "Called DoSomething with SomeRandomClass whose myInt member has value " << t.myInt << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << "Called DoSomething with a type that is not SomeRandomClass\n";
    }
};
```

type-traits were a way to simulate this without needing a class specialization.

Note that `is_random_class` here is a stand-in for an arbitrary constraint. In general, if you're only checking for a single nontemplated type, prefer a normal overload because it's more efficient on the compiler.

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nJKfSMWtkry1xjq4)

---

### C++20

In **C++20**, we can take this a step further and use a [constraint](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) instead of `if constexpr` by using a `requires` clause on our templated member function. The downside is that we again move back to two functions; one that matches the constraint, and another that doesn't:

```
struct MyNonTemplatedClass
{
    template<class T>  requires is_random_class_v<T>
    void DoSomething(T& t)
    {
        std::cout << "Called DoSomething with SomeRandomClass whose myInt member has value " << t.myInt << std::endl;
    }
    
    template<class T> requires !is_random_class_v<T>
    void DoSomething(T&) 
    {
        std::cout << "Called DoSomething with a type that is not SomeRandomClass\n";
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yxyuuop2RfkOD7Cb)

---

Also in C++ 20, we could explicitly encode a concept and use abbreviated template syntax:

```
template<class T>
concept IsRandomClass = is_random_class_v<T>;

template<class T>
concept IsNotRandomClass = !is_random_class_v<T>;

// ...

template<IsRandomClass T>
void DoSomething(T& t)
{ /*...*/}

template<IsNotRandomClass T>
void DoSomething(T&)
{ /*...*/}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zWvdra7MM)

Comment: If in 2010 you wanted your code to compile with gcc on rhel4 and rhel5, and with visual studio 2008 on windows xp, this is the way you would have written it too.

Comment: You are giving a very detailed answer.
But why do we need the template struct `is_random_class` in the C++17 version?
Some pointers on that could be appreciated

Comment: @KrisztiánSzegi: Ultimately we need a way to detect of the type `T` is an instantiation of the template `template<class A, class B>
class SomeRandomClass` We need a way to "fill in" the template arguments for `A` and `B` because a template doesn't exist until its instantiated (that is, we need a concrete type).  At the scope of `template<class T>` void DoSomething` we have no way to specify these parameters; we only have `T`. So we want to interrogate `T` to see if, by providing 2 template parameters `A` and `B` (called `T` and `S` in the code), we can match it. (cont...)

Comment: @KrisztiánSzegi (cont from prev) So we wrote the type trait (`is_random_class`) as a way to match `T` into `SomeRandomClass<A, B>`. The primary template (that only accepts a single template parameter) is a catch-all for everything that is *not* an instance of `SomeRandomClass<A, B>`. The following template specialization finally provides the two template parameters to match  against `A` and `B`, and the compiler will see that this specialization is a "better" match for types that are instantiations of `SomeRandomClass`. Hope that helps.

Comment: That sort of answers it, what is unclear that why cannot I write the `is_random_class_v` as a templated constexpr **function** (one catch-all, and one specialization for `SomeRandomClass` as with the struct), and call *that* in  `DoSomething`?
The constexpr variable **and** the underlying struct seems one layer too many of abstractions.

Comment: Seems like that would fall under function template partial specialization, which is not (yet?) allowed by the standard.
I meant something along these lines: https://godbolt.org/z/onb64qMf9.

Using structs and the likes feels like a hackery to statisfy the compiler, while the one above seems *just as much input info* as the one that is working...

Comment: @KrisztiánSzegi Right, partially specialized functions are not a thing in C++. C++ from the beginning has always been about having a robust type system, so classes are the primary way of communicating meta-information.

Comment: With the continuous improvements, this is definitely a top quality answer!
I like the C++20 Concept addition, and eagerly waiting for the day we set `CXX_STANDARD 20` in our CMake projects at my workplace

Answer (score 10):

All you need to do is just template on what you want to keep generic.  Taking what you started with:

```
template<typename T, typename S>
void MyTemplateClass< SomeRandomClass<T,S> >::DoSomething(SomeRandomClass<T,S> & t)
{
    //something specialized happens here
}
```

EDIT:

Alternatively, if you only want to keep part of the `SomeRandomClass` generic, you could:

```
template<typename T>
void MyTemplateClass< SomeRandomClass<T,int> >::DoSomething(SomeRandomClass<T,int> & t)
{
    //something specialized happens here
}
```

Comment: Those I think that's almost it, however I can't get it to compile (with g++ or intel).  I think putting the template<typename T> there confuses the compiler into not recognizing that as a specialization (ie there needs to be a template<> , correct?)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** this is a correct answer to a different question.

Using the typename `T` twice confuses the issue a little, because they are compiled separately and are not connected in any way.

You can overload the method to take a templated parameter:

```
template <typename T>
class MyTemplateClass
{
    void DoSomething(T& t) { }

    template <typename U,typename V>
    void DoSomething(SomeRandomClass<<U,V>& r) { }
};
```

This maps `U` and `V` in the new method to `T'` and `S'` in `SomeRandomClass`. In this setup, either `U` or `V` could be the same type as `T`, but they don't have to be. Depending on your compiler, you ought to be able to do

```
MyTemplateClass<string> mine;
SomeRandomClass<int,double> random;

// note: nevermind the non-const ref on the string literal here...
mine.DoSomething("hello world");
mine.DoSomething(random);
```

and the templated call will be selected as the matching overload without having to respecify the types explicitly.

**Edit:**

To do with with template specialization makes no difference to the overload of `DoSomething`. If you specialize the class as follows

```
template <>
class SomeRandomClass <int,double>
{
    // something here...
};
```

then the overload above will eat up this specialized implementation gladly. Just be sure the interfaces of the specialized template and the default template match.

If what you're wanting is to specialize `DoSomething` to take a specific pair of types for `SomeRandomClass` then you've already lost generality...that's what specialization is.

Comment: That's not quite it. That looks like it's just overloading of the DoSomething member, rather than a specialization of the class itself.

Comment: You're right, but it makes no difference to the method overload whether you're passing a specialized class or a regular template.

Comment: I finally see now what you were asking. This answer was totally backward.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use provide a template struct as a template argument (with intent to use it inside) without specializing it:

Here is an example, that appends a type to a tuple given a template sfinae struct as a template argument:

```
template<typename Tuple, typename T, template<typename> class /*SFINAEPredicate*/>
        struct append_if;

        template<typename T, template<typename> class SFINAEPredicate, typename ... Types>
        struct append_if<std::tuple<Types...>, T, SFINAEPredicate>
        {
            using type = typename std::conditional<SFINAEPredicate<T>::value,
                    std::tuple<Types..., T>, std::tuple<Types...>>::type;
        };


    // usage
    using tuple_with_int = append_if<std::tuple<>, int, std::is_fundamental>;
```

This can be used since C++11.