# Specialization that is itself a template

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, template-meta-programming

I have a template class that I have some specializations for.
But the next specialization is a template itself. How do you specify this:

```
template<typename T>
class Action
{
    public: void doStuff()  { std::cout << "Generic\n"; }
}

// A specialization for a person
template<>
class Action<Person>
{
    public: void doStuff()  { std::cout << "A Person\n";}
}


// I can easily specialize for vectors of a particular type.
// But how  do I change the following so that it works with all types of vector.
// Not just `int`
template<>
class Action<std::vector<int> >
{
    public: void doStuff()  { std::cout << "A Generic Vector\n";}
}
```

Comment: I'm just wondering that you don't know this!

Comment: @Nawaz: my thought as well, a late night perhaps ?

Comment: Now that I see the answer it is obvious, but I kept adding another template line in their.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Templated class specialization where template argument is a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189945/templated-class-specialization-where-template-argument-is-a-template)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Trivial partial specialization ?

```
template <typename T>
class Action<std::vector<T>> {
public:
  void doStuff() { std::cout << "A Generic Vector\n"; }
};
```

Comment: +1. Sometimes (often?) the obvious answer is the right answer :)

Comment: @ereOn: the real question is --> why do I get so many votes for such a trivial answer :x ?

Comment: I guess people just love simplicity :)