# template class specialization with template class parameter

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

Say I have :

```
template < typename T >
class ClassA 
{
    void doTheStuff (T const * t);
};

template < typename T >
class ClassB
{
    // Some stuff...
};
```

I'd like to specialize the doTheStuff method for all instances of the ClassB template like this:

```
template <typename T>
void ClassA< ClassB< T > >::doTheStuff (ClassB< T > const * t)
{
    // Stuff done in the same way for all ClassB< T > classes
}
```

But of course, this doesn't work. Shame is I don't know how I could do that.

With visual studio's compiler I get:

```
 error C2244: 'ClassA<T>::doTheStuff' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
 see declaration of 'ClassA<T>::doTheStuff'
    definition
    'void ClassA<ClassB<T>>::doTheStuff(const ClassB<T> *)'
    existing declarations
    'void ClassA<T>::doTheStuff(const T *)'
```

I found this post: [Templated class specialization where template argument is a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189945/templated-class-specialization-where-template-argument-is-a-template)

So I tried the full class specialization as advised but it doesn't work either:

```
template <>
template < typename U >
class ClassA< ClassB< U > >
{
public:
    void doTheStuff (ClassB< U > const * b)
    {
        // Stuff done in the same way for all ClassB< T > classes
    }
};
```

Visual says:

```
error C2910: 'ClassA<ClassB<U>>' : cannot be explicitly specialized
```

Any help welcome !

Floof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the extra `template<>` and it will work.

Comment: Thanks ! It does work, I don't know why they had this extra template <> on the other thread.