# Template class specialization for vector type - different valid syntax?

Tags: c++, templates, syntax

In the following snippit, is the `template<>` optional for the specialization? Is there any difference whether I include it or not? My first instinct was to include it as it more-or-less signifies that it is a specialization. It compiles both ways under both g++ 4.9.2 and Intel 16

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct PrintMe
{
    static void Print(const T & t)
    {
        std::cout << "In general templated struct: " << t << "\n";
    }   
};      


template<> // <--- optional?
template<typename T>
struct PrintMe<std::vector<T>>
{   
    static void Print(const std::vector<T> & t)
    {   
        std::cout << "In general specialization for vector: " << t.size() << "\n";
        for(const auto & it : t)
            std::cout << "        " << it << "\n";
    }

};


int main(void)
{   
    PrintMe<int>::Print(5);   
    PrintMe<double>::Print(5);    
    PrintMe<std::vector<float>>::Print({10,20,30,40});

    return 0;
}
```

Note: Out of curiosity, I tried adding multiple `template<>`. Ie,

```
template<>
template<>
template<>
template<typename T>
struct PrintMe<std::vector<T>>
```

This still compiles with Intel, but not with g++. Not sure what that means, but it's interesting.

Note 2: Wow, this is very similar to a question of mine from 5 years ago: [Templated class specialization where template argument is a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189945/templated-class-specialization-where-template-argument-is-a-template) . There it was mentioned as redundant syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the definition of the class template,

```
template<> // <--- optional?
template<typename T>
struct PrintMe<std::vector<T>> { ... };
```

is not valid.

You need to remove that line and use:

```
template<typename T>
struct PrintMe<std::vector<T>> { ... };
```

Answer (score 0):

there are ways to look at templates and template specialization that will paint a better picture and make the whole thing clearer.
For me in this case the easier way to look at this is not to think of

```
template<typename T>
struct PrintMe<std::vector<T>> { ... };
```

as a specialization of

```
template<typename T>
struct PrintMe { ... };
```

but as a different class template altogether, it just happen to be that the two have similarly named methods.

Comment: That was also a thought I had. It seems similar to the function template specialization vs. overload argument. But in that case, there are some important details with respect to resolution, etc. Maybe that's not the case here? Printing out the typeid() shows they have the same mangled name

Comment: this is the case here and in every template, template specialization is basically you telling the compiler "don't use that other implantation, use this one I'm giving you here."

Don't know know why you say they have the same mangled name, those are two different classes in run-time and have different names.