# Template specialization for type concretized by template parameter

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

First of all I'm very sorry for the question title, but it's very hard to describe.
What of those two below is valid syntax if I want to specialized `Resolve` for all instantiation of `A`?
1)

```
template<uint32_t I> struct A {};

template<typename> struct Resolve;

template<uint32_t I>
struct Resolve<A<I>>
{
    void f() { printf("im here!\n"); }  
};
```

2)

```
template<uint32_t I> struct A {};

template<typename> struct Resolve;

template<>
template<uint32_t I>
struct Resolve<A<I>>
{
    void f() { printf("im here!\n"); }  
};
```

Or is `template<>` optional? There's two different answers on SO: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4189945/templated-class-specialization-where-template-argument-is-a-template) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911904/template-class-specialization-for-vector-type-different-valid-syntax).
Also please provide quotation of the standard if possible.

Option 2) doesn't compile on MSVC, but does compile at least on some versions of GCC.

Comment: The accepted answer of the second post clearly states that the `template <>` bit is not valid.

Comment: But unfortunately doesn't say why

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for. If there isn't anything in the standard that says it is valid, then it is invalid.

Comment: Well, maybe standard says somewhere about this sort of cases. If not, then I'll go with the answet that the first one is not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct:

```
template <uint32_t I>
struct Resolve<A<I>>
{ };
```

The syntax `template <>` is used to introduce an *explicit specialization* (of a class template, function template, whatever) (see [[temp.spec]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#spec-3.sentence-2) and [[temp.expl.spec]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#expl.spec-1)). But we're trying to do a *partial specialization*. A partial specialization still needs to introduce template parameters, an explicit specialization does not.

On the other hand, if we were trying to specialize a member of an explicit specialization, then we'd use `template <>`. For instance:

```
template <class T>
struct A {
    template <class T2> struct B { }; // #1
};

template <>         // for A
template <class T2> // for B
struct A<int>::B<T2> { }; // #2

A<char>::B<int> x; // #1
A<int>::B<char> y; // #2
```